# Case insensitive product urls

Tags: url-rewrite, htaccess, apache

Does anyone have a good solution for making magento products' URLs case insensitive?

Obviously I've looked into:

  `<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckCaseOnly on
    CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>`

However since we are using mod_rewrite that doesn't work. So we then tried:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    rewritemap lowercase int:tolower
    RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L] 
  </IfModule>`

Which worked, on the product level but broke the admin search fields and a created a few other headaches.

So now I am looking for a solution with no compromises.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the following to the httpd.conf for Apache

`RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower`

You then need to restart Apache for it to take affect. Then from here you can use the code you have in your htaccess file

Comment: Already mentioned that we tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: So to confirm RewriteMap lc int:tolower is in the httpd.conf and not the htaccess yea?

Comment: Correct, I can confirm that.